# Find third column based on group by - Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have three columns id, score1, score2. I need to create a fourth column based on firth three and column id can be grouped as the score1 and score2 are records of an id. Here is the table.

```
id  score1 score2
1   6      10
1   5      12
2   11     22
2   3      15
```

The fourth column should contain the values from the score1 column on a condition that it should return the value where the score2 is maximum in a group.

So for the above the table the score3 table has the values like below.

```
id  score1 score2 score3
1   6      10      5  
1   5      12      5
2   11     22      11
2   3      15      11
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `transform`

```
df['score3']=df.groupby('id').score1.transform('max')
df
Out[411]: 
   id  score1  score2  score3
0   1       5      10       6
1   1       6      12       6
2   2      11      22      11
3   2       3      15      11
```

Check with

```
df.id.map(df.groupby('id').score3.idxmax().map(df.score1))
Out[415]: 
0     5
1     5
2    11
3    11
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hello Wen-Ben, the condition should be based on score2 and return score1. I just edited the data in my question so that it will be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df['score3']=df.groupby('id')['score1'].transform('max')
print(df)

   id  score1  score2  score3
0   1       5      10       6
1   1       6      12       6
2   2      11      22      11
3   2       3      15      11
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sort` + `drop_duplicates` to find value to map for each `id` then map.

```
s = df.sort_values('score2').drop_duplicates('id', 'last').set_index('id').score1
df['score3'] = df.id.map(s)

   id  score1  score2  score3
0   1       6      10       5
1   1       5      12       5
2   2      11      22      11
3   2       3      15      11
```